# at-breakpoint, with-grid-settings infinite loop

Tags: compass-sass, sass

I just want to apply another grid-layout at an special breakpoint (maybe I'm doing it wrong ant thats the reason for my problem...)

If I try the following code I geht the error:

***An @include loop has been found: at-breakpoint includes itself***

```
#br-page-wrapper
{
    @include container();
    @include at-breakpoint($breakpoint-mobile-portrait)
    {
       @include with-grid-settings($layout-mobile-portrait)
       {
          @include container();
          background: red;
       }
   }
}
```

The var $layout-mobile-portrait is defined in my constants.scss:

```
$layout-mobile-portrait: 1 98% 2% 0;
```

**BUT** if I replace the variable with the values of the variable I get no error.

Comment: I don't know why you only get the error sometimes, but the `contain()` mixin calls the `at-breakpoint()` mixin under certain conditions:  https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/sass/susy/_grid.scss#L66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short:

You can do either of two things:

```
// use commas:
@include with-grid-settings(1, 98%, 2%, 0) { /* content */ }

// use varargs (with "..."):
@include with-grid-settings($layout-mobile-portrait...) { /* content */ }
```

## Long:

`container()` does call `at-breakpoint()` any time the columns requested are different from the current setting for `$total-columns`. Your problem is that you are not passing a valid value to `with-grid-settings()` because you are using a space-separated list. `with-grid-settings()` is setting that entire list as the value of `$total-columns`, which is then passed to `container()` where it gets parsed as a new layout, no longer equal to your errant `$total-columns` setting.

Comment: Hi,

it's working with varargs!!!
Didn't know about the syntax with the dots :-(

Thanky you very much, you saved me a lot of time ;)